# How to implement the t statistics in python

Tags: python, probability

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Past experience indicates that because of low morale, a company loses
>   20 hours a year per employee due to lateness and abstenteeism. Assume
>   that the standard deviation of the population is 6 and normally
>   distributed.
>
> The HR department implemented a new rewards system to increase
>   employee morale, and after a few months it collected a random sample
>   of 20 employees and the annualized absenteeism was 14.
>
> - Could you confirm that the new rewards system was effective with a 90% confidence?
> - An HR subject matter expert would be very happy if the program could reduce absenteeism by 20% (i.e. to 16 hours). Given the current
>     sampling parameters, what is the probability that the new rewards
>     system reduced absenteeism to 16 hours and you miss it?

I have the below questions.

1. Can I use normal distribution since the population distribution is
   normal or should I consider doing ttest as the sample are less than
   30
2. In order to find the critical value for the second question do I need to consider the sample mean as 14 or 16. Also I am confused
   whether to use the population mean as 20 or 16.

Comment: While interesting this looks like a homework question about statistics. Try a mother stackexchange site..? Or ask about specific libraries like scipy?

Comment: You should use the $t$-test when the population is assumed to be normally distributed but the population variance is unknown so when you are estimating the variance from the sample.  That does not seem to be the case here